# SSDP Device Discovery for Application in Java

Tags: java, udp

I have some hardware devices connected to a specific network and I have a Java application also running in the same network. I now need to detect these devices from my Java application. The specification is like this:

1. My Java program has to send a UDP packet with a host name

   `{"type":"HW-PROBER","hostname":"Host-NAME"}`
2. The hardware upon receipt of this message sends me back a response with the NOTIFICATION in the form of a Payload that looks like this:

   `{"type":"HW-NOTIFY","hostname":"Host-NAME","ip":"1.2.3.4"}`

So this way, my Java application has to get the ip address of the hardware and start communicating with it. I'm totally unclear on how to do the device discovery. Would this mean that my Java application has to open a port say at 5000 (for example.,) and keep waiting for packets? 
What sort of API from the Java standard library should I be using?